# How does mapping on an rdd work in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I was learning pyspark when I encounterd this.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row([0,45,63,0,0,0,0]),
                           Row([0,0,0,85,0,69,0]),
                           Row([0,89,56,0,0,0,0])],
                           ['features'])

+--------------------+
|            features|
+--------------------+ 
|[0, 45, 63, 0, 0,...|
|[0, 0, 0, 85, 0, ...|
|[0, 89, 56, 0, 0,...|
+--------------------+

sample = df.rdd.map(lambda row: row[0]*2)
sample.collect()

[[0, 45, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 85, 0, 69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 85, 0, 69, 0],
[0, 89, 56, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 89, 56, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

My question is why is row[0] is taken as a complete list rather than one value?
What is the property that gives the above output

Answer (score 0):

It is Taken as Complete list as you have given it as one, and you have also defined it under one column "features"

when You are saying

```
df.rdd.map(lambda row: row[0]*2)
```

You are just asking spark that "I want all values in this list to occur twice". Hence you get the output that you are getting.

Now How to get Individual values in list.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(0,45,63,0,0,0,0),
                       Row(0,0,0,85,0,69,0),
                       Row(0,89,56,0,0,0,0)],
                       ['feature1' , 'feature2' , 'feature3' , 'feature4', 'feature5' , 'feature6' , 'feature7'])
```

This should give you access to individual values in a dedicated column.

Note : syntax for schema is just representation. please refer spark docs for exact syntax.

Hope This helps :)